# Passing arguments between a script and a binary

Tags: bash

How can I pass arguments from a bash script to a binary?

I have a desktop file `app.desktop` and an wrapper `app.wrapper` that calls the app binary. I want to have `app.desktop` calling the wrapper with `Exec=./app.wrapper arg1 arg3 -a arg4` then from the `app.wrapper` to pass it to `/usr/bin/app`.

How can I easily do this?

Example of wrapper file:

```
#!/bin/bash

SCALE=$(( $GRID_UNIT_PX / 8 ))

export GDK_BACKEND=x11
export GDK_SCALE=$SCALE

exec usr/bin/app args here
```

Thanks.

Comment: In the same way as passing it to another script. Binary executables are, from the viewpoint of bash, not different from executable scripts. See the section _SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS_ in the bash man page, which describes the `exec` command. Of course a more interesting question would be, why you are using `exec` when running your binary. I hope you know what you are doing here.

Comment: Yeah, exec is probably not needed. same for `user/bin/app`, just type `app`, as `/usr/bin` is usually already in your `$PATH`

Comment: And `export` isn't really needed either; you can simply `GDK_BACKEND="x11" GDK_SCALE=$((GRID_UNIT_PX / 8)) exec app "$@"`